# Failed to fetch archives while installing gcc-4.9 g++-4.9

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-mint

Currently, I am using Linux Mint 17.3.

`E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.9/cpp-4.9_4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch`

`E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.9/g++-4.9_4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch`

`E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++ nor with programming. I've requested a move to superuser.stackexchange.com. You'll have more luck getting an answer over there.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the content of `/var/lib/apt/lists directory` :

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Install `gcc-4.9`

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9
```